# Select 20 results per every column value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I prepared query that select date from table. In table I got: rank, name, citycode as columns. When I am doing something like that:

```
select name, citycode  
from tab20
where rank <= 20
```

I got resault of first 20 rows that gets rank <= 20. And Everything would be ok, but I have to show results of first 20 rows per every citystate. Is it possible to create in one query ? I was tryin union etc but it doesn't work well.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you find citystate? Another table?

Comment: @jarlh it's in the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `row_number()` function.  Based on the `rank` that would be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by citycode order by rank) as seqnum
      from tab20 t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```